# Sumif return zero when using user defined function with a string input

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I have two columns,

Col 1 is a list of industries name eg. transportation, banks etc.
Col 2 is the corresponding amortization years
Data_RD is the codename of the sheet.

But when i use the function by inserting a string input, i do not get the years. Instead i get 0. What could be the issue?

Thanks

---

Function Amortization_Years(Industry As String) As Double

Dim myIndustry As Range

Dim myYears As Range

Set myIndustry = Data_RD.Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

Set myYears = Data_RD.Range("B2:B" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

Amortization_Years = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sumif(myIndustry, Industry, myYears)

End Function

Comment: See [the formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for how to format your code example as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

Here Range("A1") will refer to the active sheet, not Data_RD

It's good practise to always be specific about that sheet you're using.